# Remove leading zero in edittext from a custom zero button in android

Tags: android, android-edittext, zero, leading-zero

I've used `addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()` to remove leading zeroes however it only works in android soft keyboard `numpad` instead of my custom `numpad`. `n0` is the zero button. basically whenever i hit the zero button, my app crashes.

```
    //custom zero button
            n0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                        input1.append("0");
                        operationA();
                }
            });
```

I just need the code that the zero button will not return any value when clicked to avoid leading zeros. Below is the  `addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()`

```
    input1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if (s.toString().length() == 1 && s.toString().startsWith("0")) {
                    s.clear();
                }
            }
        });
```

Getting these error:

```
    AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: context, PID: 12408
        java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
            at java.lang.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1071)
            at java.lang.Double.valueOf(Double.java:511)
            at context.operationA(MainActivity.java:478)
            at context$17.onClick(MainActivity.java:383)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the error occurred when you try  to parse string as  `double` in `operationA` method but the String is Empty ,check if string is not Empty before convert it

Comment: It still crashes :( that still works on android built in soft numpad but not my custom numpad zeron button.

Comment: updated thread with the error logs. replaced address "context" so it's not too long.

Comment: the error occurred when you try  to parse string as  **double** but the String is Empty

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I solved it by writing a function below:

```
private String trimLeadingZeros(String string)
{
    boolean startsWithZero = true;
    while (startsWithZero)
    {
        if(string.startsWith("0") && string.length()>=2 && !string.substring(1,2).equalsIgnoreCase("."))
        {string = string.substring(1);}
        else
        {startsWithZero = false;}
    }
    return  string;
}
```

This function also prevents from trimming all the zeros from a string like 00000.123 (it will return 0.123 instead of useless .123).

Answer (score 0):

To remove leading zero in EditText, you can have a `TextWatcher` that detects the first typed-in zero, and clears it

```
TextWatcher watcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if (s.toString().equals("0")) {
            editText.removeTextChangedListener(this);
            editText.setText("");
            editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
};

editText.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
```